# Identify a string containing a single period with regex

Tags: c#, regex, hyperlink, ip

I am trying to write a regex operation that will simply identify if there is only one period within a string.

For example, it will recognize `arandomlink.online` and `a@second#random-link.fr`, but it will not recognize an IPV4 IP Address with multiple periods, like `5.6.7.8`.

I'm currently using:

```
string URLpattern = @"\w*\.\w";
```

but the code above identifies IP addresses, which I don't want.

Anybody have any ideas? It's probably a very simple equation, but it's not coming to me right now. I can't figure out how to limit the equation to only identifying one period within the string, and not multiple. Because I'm working with Hash's and other things, it's best if I identify the URL's with the single period.

Comment: What about URLs with a complex TLD like `.co.uk`?

Comment: I'm not going to answer, I'm on my phone and can't test it, but `[^\.]*` means 0 or more characters that are not periods, and `\.` matches a single dot, so I'm pretty sure that `[^\.]*\.[^\.]*` would do what you want (as long as the string length was greater than 1)

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks for the response! I'm going to add some URL's with multiple periods as exceptions. It's the most convenient way to do that. I might not hit all of them, but the more I get, the better.

Comment: @Flydog57 Thanks for the response! What you are saying makes sense, Unfortunately what you wrote captures IP Addresses too. I'll play around with it and see if I can modify what you suggested to work.

Comment: It will match an IP address, but, if you check, it will be multiple captures, one per dot

Comment: Use `Regex.IsMatch(text, @"^[^.]*\.[^.]*$")`

Comment: Does it need to be a regex? Why not simply `var exactlyOnePeriod = myString.Count(c => c == '.') == 1;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are coding in C#, it makes sense to use a non-regex approach here (see [Klaus Gütter's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69329372/identify-a-string-containing-a-single-period-with-regex/69329692#comment122542649_69329372)):

```cs
var ContainsOnlyOneDot = text.Count(c => c == '.') == 1;
```

If you have to do that with a regex, you can use

```cs
^[^.]*\.[^.]*$
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5B%5E.%5Cn%5D*%5C.%5B%5E.%5Cn%5D*%24&i=123%0D%0Aabc.def%0D%0Aabcdef%0D%0Aryt.rrt.ty&o=m). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[^.]*` - zero or more chars other than `.`
- `\.` - a dot
- `[^.]*` - zero or more chars other than a `.` char
- `$` - end of string.

In C#, you can use

```cs
if (Regex.IsMatch(text, @"^[^.]*\.[^.]*$"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("The string contains one dot only.");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("The string contains no dots or more than one dot.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```regex
[^\s\.]+\.{1}[^\s\.]+
```

So one dot surrounded with negating sets of anything except a dot and a whitespace.